# Form action event not working on popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I have a form inside popup but my form action event not working after click on button.

My code:

```js
$.fn.expose = function(options) {

  var $modal = $(this),
    $trigger = $("a[href=" + this.selector + "]");

  $modal.on("expose:open", function() {

    $modal.addClass("is-visible");
    $modal.trigger("expose:opened");
  });

  $modal.on("expose:close", function() {

    $modal.removeClass("is-visible");
    $modal.trigger("expose:closed");
  });

  $trigger.on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $modal.trigger("expose:open");
  });

  $modal.add($modal.find(".close")).on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // if it isn't the background or close button, bail
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;

    $modal.trigger("expose:close");
  });

  return;
}

$("#Popup").expose();

// Example Cancel Button

$(".cancel").on("click", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger("expose:close");
});
```

```css
.Modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.Modal .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(0);
}
.Modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #2ecc71;
  color: #fff;
}
.Modal .close:before {
  content: '\2715';
}
.Modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: background .35s;
  -moz-transition: background .35s;
  transition: background .35s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .1s;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}
.Modal.is-visible .content {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: transition: transform .35s;
  -moz-transform: transition: transform .35s;
  transition: transform .35s;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: 125px auto 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #2ecc71;
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 09px 0px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Popup" class="button">Expose Modal</a>
<!--popup content here-->
<div id="Popup" class="Modal">
  <div class="content">
    <form action="demo.php" method="post" id="register-form">

      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name:" id="name">
      <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location:" id="location">

      <div class="center-text vpadding">
        <input type="submit" value="request now" class="button-request">
      </div>
    </form>

    <span class="close"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Please check my code here https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/sh0u3xze/

Comment: Mr.Shubham Khatri. Please also upload CSS

Comment: CSS is not relevant in solving you problem. Anyways I will edit it again.

Comment: Cool.Thanks Mr.Shubham Khatri.

Comment: @Hybreeder You have an un-necessary `e.preventDefault();`  in your modal click eventlistener. Just remove it. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an `e.preventDefault();` that was blocking your form-action. SImply remove it from the modal click event listener. Everything will work as expected. No additional code or triggering required.

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/f1wh41fm/2/

Change this

```
$modal.add( $modal.find(".close") ).on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // if it isn't the background or close button, bail
    if( e.target !== this )
      return;

    $modal.trigger("expose:close");
  });
```

to

```
$modal.add( $modal.find(".close") ).on("click", function(e) {

    //e.preventDefault();

    // if it isn't the background or close button, bail
    if( e.target !== this )
      return;

    $modal.trigger("expose:close");
  });
```

**EDIT**

For input-cursor indentation as you requested, Use the [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-indent) property: :

```
input {
  text-indent:20px;
}
```

Comment: Cool. Mr.Iceman. Can you help me in placeholder because when i clicked on textbox my cursor in showing on left side. I have to display left 15px

Comment: You mean only the cursor?

Comment: yes you can check when i clicked on text field my cursor position is showing on left side that is not good.

Comment: input {
  text-indent:20px;
}

Comment: Thank u very much Mr.iceman..appreciate your support. Thank u very much again.

Comment: @Hybreeder Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So now I added this onClick submit action to you code and looks like its working. Try it out.

```
$(".button-request").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $modal.trigger("expose:close");
        $("#register-form").submit();
    });
```

**Complete JS**

```
$.fn.expose = function(options) {

  var $modal = $(this),
      $trigger = $("a[href=" + this.selector + "]");

  $modal.on("expose:open", function() {

    $modal.addClass("is-visible");
    $modal.trigger("expose:opened");
  });

  $modal.on("expose:close", function() {

    $modal.removeClass("is-visible");
    $modal.trigger("expose:closed");
  });

  $trigger.on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $modal.trigger("expose:open");
  });
   $(".button-request").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $modal.trigger("expose:close");
        $("#register-form").submit();
    });

  $modal.add( $modal.find(".close") ).on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // if it isn't the background or close button, bail
    if( e.target !== this )
      return;

    $modal.trigger("expose:close");
  });

  return;
}

$("#Popup").expose();

// Example Cancel Button

$(".cancel").on("click", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger("expose:close");
});
```

For input to align 15px right use `text-indent` css property

```
input[type="text"]
{
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 09px 0px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-indent: 15px;

}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0u3xze/2/)**

Comment: Sure this works. But, what is over-riding the original form action event?

Comment: Yes because the original form submit action was'nt firing at all.I checked the Network request in the browser.

Comment: Yes because and event blocker was blocking the event. The network tab will not list events blocked at the javascript level.

Comment: Cool. Mr.Shubham Khatri . Can you help me in placeholder because when i clicked on textbox my cursor in showing on left side. I have to display left 15px

Comment: @Hybreeder I could'nt understand your problem. Could you explain a little more